# Linux able to read data in my external hard drive while windows can't

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I have an external USB hard drive ,recently I connect it to my laptop while windows  through USB,windows say say the data corrupted and even can't enter the hard drive through explorer ,I decided to boot through Linux(Ubuntu),and I **found out that Linux can see all the files and read and it ,and it's not corrupted ,I'm happy now my data is safe,but I want to know what is the root of the problem ? is there is a software on windows can by pass this issue and can read the files like what Linux did without even any software ?**

Comment: What kind of file system you are using on the  USB hard drive? How did you format it? How many partitions do you have there? Post output of `cat /proc/partitions` under Linux

Comment: the external Hard-disk file system type is NTFS file system time .

Comment: sorry I formatted the hard drive already before you updated your comment